# Selector li + li trouble

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I use to use a background image usually on my li + li for a little sliver seperator on my nav menu and I was wanting to try to create  a separator without a image (horrible explanation).

I previously was using

```
#header li + li {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/IdVT0cL.png') 8px 8px / 1px 10px no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

So I tried

```
#header li + li {
    background: #00B25C 8px 8px / 1px 10px no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

And it's highlighting the all the list items except the first one. Why is this? Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yhLLb/

Comment: `li + li` selects the adjacent `<li>` sibling of an `<li>` element. So the first `<li>` can't be the adjacent sibling of anything. In other words, `li + li` says to select the `<li>` that comes immediately *after* another `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you could use css' :before-selector to achieve a separator without using an image:

```
#navBar li+li:before {
    content: "|";
    /*background: #00B25C 8px 8px / 1px 10px no-repeat;*/
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yhLLb/2/

Cheers
Florian

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question, why is it highlighting all the list items except the first one, can be explained by the spec for the CSS adjacent selector.
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

> Thus, the following rule states that when a P element immediately
>   follows a MATH element, it should not be indented:
>
> math + p { text-indent: 0 }

This fiddle highlights all of the menu items, not sure if this is what you wanted to achieve though, as #navBar li would suffice, there is no need to select the adjacent element?
http://jsfiddle.net/yhLLb/1/

i.e.

```
#navBar li, #navBar li + li {
    background: #00B25C 8px 8px / 1px 10px no-repeat;
}
```

is the same as

```
#navBar li {
    background: #00B25C 8px 8px / 1px 10px no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: If I did something like

#navBar li {
    background: #00B25C 8px 8px / 1px 10px no-repeat;
}

then the last one would have something after it. I only want a separator between each two.

Comment: then this way might be better for you http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that you could do it too.

html

```
    <div id="navBar">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li class="last">About</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Css

```
#navBar {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #3840F8;
    float: right;
    line-height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 40px;
}
#navBar ul {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
#navBar li {
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #888;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
}
#navBar li.last {
     border-right: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhLLb/7/)